# Can I send data form cordova app form to joomla web form?

Tags: php, forms, cordova, joomla

Is it possible to send data from a Cordova to a Joomla web form and then submit the form?

I cannot load the form in to the app and send because of " invalid token " issue.

I need help with the javascript code, the solution I have below is something is not complete but I think I'm going in the right direction.

```
<script>
    function UpdateRecord() {
        var name = $("[name='name']").val();
        var subject = $("[name='subject']").val();
        var select-choice-1']").val() = $("[name='select-choice-1']").val();
        var textarea = $("[name='textarea']").val();
        var file = $("[name='file']").val();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://website.com/send-form",
            data: "name="+ name+"& subject="+ subject+"& select-choice-1="+ select-choice-1+" & textarea="+ textarea+"+" & file="+ file+",
            dataType: "html",      
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                alert("Email Sent");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

end of javascript

```
// form on app 
<form>
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="text-basic">Text input:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="text-basic" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="text-basic">Text input:</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" id="text-basic" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Custom select:</label>
        <div class="ui-select">
            <a href="#" role="button" id="select-choice-1-button" aria-haspopup="true" class="ui-btn ui-icon-carat-d ui-btn-icon-right ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-li-has-count">
                <span>&nbsp;</span>
                <span class="ui-li-count ui-body-inherit" style="display: none;">0</span>
            </a>
            <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-native-menu="false" multiple="multiple" tabindex="-1">
                <option value="16">Item 1</option>
                <option value="15">Item 2</option>
                <option value="14">Item 3</option>
                <option value="13">Item 4</option>
                <option value="12">Item 5</option>
                <option value="9">Item 6</option>
                <option value="8">Item 7</option>
            </select>
            <div style="display: none;" id="select-choice-1-listbox-placeholder"><!-- placeholder for select-choice-1-listbox --></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="textarea">Textarea:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="textarea" id="textarea"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="file">File:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="submit-1">Send form:</label>
        <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Send<input type="submit" id="submit-1" onclick="UpdateRecord()" value="Send"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

the form in the app will post to the form on the website

```
// joomla web form

<form id="item-submission" action="/submit-a-request/submission/submission/submit-a-request/maintenance-request/a2db427bfdc794d3695d8ac6843cb04d" method="post" name="submissionForm" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="elements[0c7f7be5-059b-4cd3-8641-d88f4199af01][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">
    <input type="text" name="elements[bc797942-f95f-438e-ad05-e44b2199e9a8][0][value]" value="" size="60" maxlength="255">
    <select id="elements_itemcategoryvalue" name="elements[_itemcategory][value][]" title="Category" size="7">
        <option value="16">Item 1</option>
        <option value="15">Item 2</option>
        <option value="14">Item 3</option>
        <option value="13">Item 4</option>
        <option value="12">Item 5</option>
        <option value="9">Item 6</option>
        <option value="8">Item 7</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="elements[169f7b63-e778-4a1b-ac22-654c2e248bca][0][value]" cols="60" rows="20"> Description</textarea>
    <textarea name="elements[72d27f11-f7b4-4d8e-b076-5c35f8e896de][0][value]" cols="60" rows="20"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="filename054c769a-f6d0-4db0-b784-129f9f0d4d78" readonly="readonly">
    <input type="file" name="elements_054c769a-f6d0-4db0-b784-129f9f0d4d78" onchange="javascript: document.getElementById('filename054c769a-f6d0-4db0-b784-129f9f0d4d78').value = this.value.replace(/^.*[\/\\]/g, '');">

    <div class="submit">
        <button type="submit" id="submit-button" class="button-green">Submit Item</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible. Cordova apps simply require a few [CORS](https://www.maxcdn.com/one/visual-glossary/cors/) changes in order to get AJAX working properly.

First, make sure you have the [Cordova whitelist plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/).

Second, make sure you have the follow in your `config.xml` file:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

That should work, though you may also need to specify a `Content-Security-Policy` META in your headers. This line is about as safe as you can get in that regard:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">
```

And of course, you'll also need to make sure you have CORS on your server. If you don't have access to Apache, you can set that with:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

Hope this helps! :)

**EDIT**:

As for how to actually send data to the form, that depends on how you want the data to be *received*. I'm going to assume that as you're attempting to do it via HTML, that you're expecting a submission along the lines of `http://website.com/send-form?name=John&age=34`.

The main problem with the way you're currently submitting your data is the spaces: `data: "name="+ name+"& subject="+ subject+"`. Strip those.

```
data: "name="+name+"&subject="+subject+"&select-choice-1="+select-choice-1+"& textarea="+textarea+"+"&file="+file+",
```

Depending on how you're running the back end, you may need to pass `?` at the end of the script, to denote that whatever follows should be considered variables. If this is the case, you would replace `url: "http://website.com/send-form"` with `url: "http://website.com/send-form?"`.

I'd also recommend looking into the [AJAX documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) regarding how to pass the data through to your form, so that you can adjust code accordingly.

**EDIT 2**

To submit the form through JavaScript, you need to use:

```
document.forms["loginForm"].submit();
```

Please note that `loginForm` in my example corresponds to the form ID, which you haven't set. In this case I used `loginForm`, so you would need to change your HTML to reflect this:

```
// form on app 
<form id='loginForm'>
```

It's also possible to submit forms without an ID, but it's a little harder. You *should* only have one form on your page, so you can probably also use:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

Without knowing the form ID, as `document.forms` is actually an array.

See [here](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml) for a little further reading.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I need help with javascript code? how do I sent data form form A to Form B?

Comment: There's many ways to do it, and you're very close to one of the ways -- you just have a slight error in your syntax. I've updated my answer to cover this. I also recommend working out exactly how you want the data to be *submitted* from the form -- that is where the AJAX should be posting to.

Comment: how do i trigger the Send button on the web form?

Comment: I've added a new edit in the answer to cover this as well, though this was not your initial question, and should constitute a separate question.

Comment: my question was how to write jquery to send data form form A to form B and  then send form B without touching form B... Form B is a joomla form if you are familiar with that